# How to use C++ `size()` as parameter to function when implementing vector

Tags: c++, class, vector

As the title states, I need to use the `size()` function call as a parameter to a different function. Here's what I'm trying to do here. As part of the STL, I am trying to use the `reserve()` function to allocate the exact amount of space I need. 
I thought this would be very straightforward, but when I compile, I get an error message stating: 
`./faculty.h:69:17: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
  void reserve (size());`

Any ideas on how to fix this? I don't understand why this isn't working as I thought it should.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with that line at all, I'm afraid. And neither your title nor description clears it up.

Comment: I would think that "using the size function call  as a parameter to a different function" means *calling* `reserve(size());`. I have no idea what it means in this case.

Comment: `: theName(name), reserve ( sections.size ( maxSections ) ), sections.size ( maxSections )` is nonsense... you can only provide initializers for objects but `reserve` is a function and `sections.size` is not a member

Comment: `void reserve (size());` is neither a function declaration nor a function calling. To declare the function, `void reserve ( size_t size );`

Answer (score 1):

You can call like

```
reserve(size());
```

But declaration of the function says what kind of argument the function expects. And it is not size(), but size_t

Try this, instead

```
reserve(size_t allocSize);
```

your code will not work and it is not straightforward at all..

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration for `void reserve()` needs to have a type specified for its parameters.  for example your `void push_back` takes a type `const Section&`.  Your declaration cannot take a function call as a parameter type.